# Best way to remove an entry from a hash table

Tags: data-structures, hashtable

What is the best way to remove an entry from a hashtable that uses linear probing? One way to do this would be to use a flag to indicate deleted elements? Are there any ways better than this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

An easy technique is to:

1. Find and remove the desired element
2. Go to the next bucket
3. If the bucket is empty, quit
4. If the bucket is full, delete the element in that bucket and re-add it to the hash table using the normal means. The item must be removed before re-adding, because it is likely that the item could be added back into its original spot.
5. Repeat step 2.

This technique keeps your table tidy at the expense of slightly slower deletions.

Comment: The trouble is this may require an O(n) operation to fill the hole in the hash table, where n is the number of slots in the hash table.

Answer (score 18):

It depends on how you handle overflow and whether (1) the item being removed is in an overflow slot or not, and (2) if there are overflow items beyond the item being removed, whether they have the hash key of the item being removed or possibly some other hash key. [Overlooking that double condition is a common source of bugs in deletion implementations.]

If collisions overflow into a linked list, it is pretty easy.  You're either popping up the list (which may have gone empty) or deleting a member from the middle or end of the linked list.  Those are fun and not particularly difficult.  There can be other optimizations to avoid excessive memory allocations and freeings to make this even more efficient.

For linear probing, Knuth suggests that a simple approach is to have a way to mark a slot as empty, deleted, or occupied.   Mark a removed occupant slot as deleted so that overflow by linear probing will skip past it, but if an insertion is needed, you can fill the first deleted slot that you passed over  [The Art of Computer Programming, vol.3: Sorting and Searching, section 6.4 Hashing, p. 533 (ed.2)].  This assumes that deletions are rather rare.

Knuth gives a nice refinment as Algorithm R6.4 [pp. 533-534] that instead marks the cell as empty rather than deleted, and then finds ways to move table entries back closer to their initial-probe location by moving the hole that was just made until it ends up next to another hole.

Knuth cautions that this will move existing still-occupied slot entries and is not a good idea if pointers to the slots are being held onto outside of the hash table. [If you have garbage-collected- or other managed-references in the slots, it is all right to move the slot, since it is the reference that is being used outside of the table and it doesn't matter where the slot that references the same object is in the table.]

Answer (score 10):

The Python hash table implementation (arguable very fast) uses dummy elements to mark deletions.  As you grow or shrink or table (assuming you're not doing a fixed-size table), you can drop the dummies at the same time.

If you have access to a copy, have a look at the article in [Beautiful Code](http://books.google.ca/books?id=gJrmszNHQV4C&pg=RA3-PA297&lpg=RA3-PA297&dq=python+hash+table+beautiful+code&source=bl&ots=rKQ-uzQ8th&sig=OMSl1cL_89CwxgmWoJZUIKuh81c&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=5&ct=result) about the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The best general solutions I can think of include:

- If you're can use a non-const iterator (ala C++ STL or Java), you should be able to remove them as you encounter them.  Presumably, though, you wouldn't be asking this question unless you're using a const iterator or an enumerator which would be invalidated if the underlying collection is modified.
- As you said, you could mark a deleted flag within the contained object.  This doesn't release any memory or reduce collisions on the key, though, so it's not the best solution.  Also requires the addition of a property on the class that probably doesn't really belong there.  If this bothers you as much as it would me, or if you simply can't add a flag to the stored object (perhaps you don't control the class), you could store these flags in a separate hash table.  This requires the most long-term memory use.
- Push the keys of the to-be-removed items into a vector or array list while traversing the hash table.  After releasing the enumerator, loop through this secondary list and remove the keys from the hash table.  If you have a lot of items to remove and/or the keys are large (which they shouldn't be), this may not be the best solution.
- If you're going to end up removing more items from the hash table than you're leaving in there, it may be better to create a new hash table, and as you traverse your original one, add to the new hash table only the items you're going to keep.  Then replace your reference(s) to the old hash table with the new one.  This saves a secondary list iteration, but it's probably only efficient if the new hash table will have significantly fewer items than the original one, and it definitely only works if you can change all the references to the original hash table, of course.
- If your hash table gives you access to its collection of keys, you may be able to iterate through those and remove items from the hash table in one pass.
- If your hash table or some helper in your library provides you with predicate-based collection modifiers, you may have a Remove() function to which you can pass a lambda expression or function pointer to identify the items to remove.

Answer (score 1):

A common technique when time is a factor is to have a second table of deleted items, and clean up the main table when you have time. Commonly used in search engines.

Answer (score 0):

How about enhancing the hash table to contain pointers like a linked list?
When you insert, if the bucket is full, create a pointer from this bucket to the bucket where the new field in stored.

While deleting something from the hashtable, the solution will be equivalent to how you write a function to delete a node from linkedlist.