# Hashmap Inserts O(N)?

Tags: hashmap

So, let's say you have a hashmap that uses linear probing.

You first insert a value X with key X, which hashes to location 5, say.

You then insert a value Y with key Y, which also hashes to 5. It will take location 6.

You then insert a value Z with key Z, which also hashes to 5. It will take location 7.

You then delete Y, so the memory looks like "X, null, Z"

You then try to insert a value with key Z, it will check 5, see it's taken, check 6, and then insert it there as its empty. However, there is already an entry with key Z, so you'll have two entries with key Z, which is against the invariant.

So wouldn't you therefore need to go through the entire map until you found the value itself. If it's not found, then you can insert it into the first null space. Therefore wouldn't all first-time inserts on a certain key be O(N)?

Comment: I had the problem wrong, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279539/best-way-to-remove-an-entry-from-a-hash-table for various techniques to deal with deletions when using probing. Deletions with a chaining implementation are a bit easier, as can be imagined.

Answer (score 3):

No.

The problem you're running into is caused by the deletion, which you've done incorrectly.

In fact, deletion from a table using linear probing is somewhat difficult -- to the point that many tables built using linear probing simply don't support deletion at all.

That said: at least in theory, nearly all operations on a hash table *can* end up linear in the worst case (insertion, deletion, lookup, etc.) Regardless of how clever a hash function you write, there are infinite inputs that can hash to any particular output. With a sufficiently unfortunate choice of inputs (or just a poor hash function) you can end up with an arbitrary percentage all producing the same hash code.

Edit: if you insist on supporting deletion with linear probing, the basic idea is that you need to ensure that each "chain" of entries remains contiguous. So, you hash the key, then walk from there all the way to the next empty bucket. You check the hash code for each of those entries, and fill the "hole" with the last contiguous item that hashed to a position before the hole. That, in turn, may create another hole that you have to fill in with the last item that hashed to a position before that hole you're creating (and so on, recursively).

Comment: So to insert a key, I shouldn't go through the list until I find the same key? It seems like deletion should also go through the entire list until it finds the key and just remove the entry, no?

Comment: Yes, to insert a key, you potentially keep walking until you get to an empty bucket. I've edited the answer to give a better idea of how you handle deletion. Bottom line: yes, you almost always want to avoid linear probing.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure why the village idiot (;)) deleted his post, since he was right -- an overcommitted/unbalanced hash table degenerates into a linear search.

To achieve O(1) performance the table must not be overcommitted (the table must be sufficiently oversized, given the number of entries), and the hash algorithm must do a good job (avoiding imbalance), given the characteristics/statistics of the key value.

It should be noted that there are two basic hash table schemes -- linear probing, where hash synonyms are simply inserted into the next available table slot, and linked lists, where hash synonyms are added to a linked list off the table element for the given hash value.  They produce roughly the same statistics until overcommitted/unbalanced, at which point linear probing quickly falls completely apart while linked lists simply degrade slowly.  And, as someone else stated, linear probing makes deletions very difficult.

Comment: There are a number of other collision resolution schemes, such as rehashing, quadratic hashing, overflow areas, or probing with a fixed increment larger than 1 (generally a number that's prime relative to the table size). The big win these have over collision chaining is that they eliminate the pointers for the linked list, *so* for the same total memory usage, then cay have far more buckets.

Comment: Yeah, rehashing I ran into ca 1981 in the old MS library files -- it's a minor variation on the linear hashing.  (Though there was an interesting bug in their implementation.)  And overflow areas are just a variation on chains.  Mostly these schemes seem to be used for static tables, where the parameters can be "tuned" based on the specific data stored.  There are also techniques such as variable sized chain elements (with several entries per element), but the concepts don't change much.