# Remove an Element From HashTable?

Tags: java, hashtable

I want to remove elements from `HashTable`,
I use `hashTable.remove()` for this but not getting

```
Hashtable<Integer,String> players = new Hashtable<Integer,String>();

        players.put(1, "Sachin Tendulkar");
        players.put(2, "Rahul Dravid");
        players.put(3, "Virat Kohli");
        players.put(4, "Rohit Sharma");

        Enumeration<String> enumration = players.elements();

        while(enumration.hasMoreElements()){
            String elmnt = enumration.nextElement();
            System.out.println(elmnt);
            if(elmnt.startsWith("R")){
                players.remove(elmnt);
                System.out.println(elmnt+"::Contains R");
            }

        }

        System.out.println(players);
```

The output that i get is:

```
Rohit Sharma
Rohit Sharma::Contains R
Virat Kohli
Rahul Dravid
Rahul Dravid::Contains R
Sachin Tendulkar
{4=Rohit Sharma, 3=Virat Kohli, 2=Rahul Dravid, 1=Sachin Tendulkar}
```

Comment: Why not use iterator and use remove() using it?

Comment: You are fetching the values using players.elements() and then trying to remove elements from the hashtable using the values, not the keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're trying to remove the value, but the `remove()` method expects a key.

When you're calling `player.elements()` you get an enumeration of the **values**, not the keys. The `remove()` method works on a key, not a value.

From [HashTable remove() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)

> **public V remove(Object key)**:
>   Removes the key (and its corresponding value) from this hashtable. This method does nothing if the key is not in the hashtable.

Also, from the same [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), here's a brief explanation on why it is **not** a good idea to use `Enumeration` to remove elements:

> Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future. The Enumerations returned by Hashtable's keys and elements methods are not fail-fast.

What I would suggest you to do is to iterate over the **entries**, not the values.

```
for (Entry<Integer, String> entry: players.entrySet()){
        String value = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(value);
        if(value.startsWith("R")){
            players.remove(entry.getKey());
            System.out.println(value+"::Contains R");
        }
}
```

This way you have both the key and the value in each iteration. You can examine the `value` (which is the player's name) and then use the `key` in order to manipulate your table.

Answer (score 1):

please add `key` to `remove()` method rather than `value`.

```
    Hashtable<String, Integer> h = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
    h.put("n1", 30);
    h.put("n2", 30);
    h.remove("n1"); //here we are giving "n1" which is key of the hashTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    for(Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> iter =  players.entrySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        Map.Entry<Integer, String> e = iter.next();
        if(e.getValue().startsWith("R")) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `key` as argument in `hashTable.remove()` to remove from `HashTable`.

Reference : [Remove from HashTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)

[Best way to remove an entry from a hash table.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279539/best-way-to-remove-an-entry-from-a-hash-table)
This may be helpful to you, have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove from enumerations.

[Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> "Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails
>   quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic
>   behavior at an undetermined time in the future. The Enumerations
>   returned by Hashtable's keys and elements methods are not fail-fast."

You should using [iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html):

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hashtable<Integer,String> players = new Hashtable<Integer,String>();

        players.put(1, "Sachin Tendulkar");
        players.put(2, "Rahul Dravid");
        players.put(3, "Virat Kohli");
        players.put(4, "Rohit Sharma");

       Iterator<Integer> iterators = players.keySet().iterator();
       while(iterators.hasNext()) {
           int key = iterators.next();
           if(players.get(key).startsWith("R")) {
               iterators.remove();
           }
       }

        System.out.println(players);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`players.remove(elmnt);` method try to remove the entry of `elmt` key. But you passed `value` of `Hashtable` instead of `key`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `players.keySet()` to get the keys in place of `players.elements()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your syntax for coding for removing an element from hash tables:-

public virtual void Remove(
    Object key
)

A mutual hash table can be manipulated with hash ref and hash remove. Concurrently by multiple threads and the operations are protected by a table-specific semaphore as needed.
Whereas, Deleting a record must not hinder later searches. In other words, the search process must still pass through the newly emptied  slot to reach records whose probe sequence passed through this slot.